# What's an elegant way to parse this text in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**Disclaimer**:
The parsing-problem described in here is very simple. This question does not simply ask for a way to achieve the parsing. - That's almost straightforward - Instead, it asks for an elegant way. That elegant way would probably be one which **does not** first read line-wise and then parse each line on its own, as this is obviously not necessary. However, is this elegant way possible with ready to use standard classes?

**Question:**
I have to parse text of the following form in java (there is more than these 3 records; records can have way more lines than these examples):

```
5
Dominik 3 
Markus 3 2
Reiner 1 2
Samantha 4 
Thomas 3
4
Babette 1 4 
Diana 3 4 
Magan 2 
Thomas 2 4
```

The first number n is the number of lines in the record directly following. Each record consists of a name and then 0 to n integers.

I thought that using `java.util.Scanner` is a natural choice, but it leads to the nastiness that when using `hasNextInt()` and `hasNext()` to determine if a line is started, I can't distinguish if a read number is the header of the next record or it's the last number behind the last name of the previous record. Example from above:

```
...
Thomas 3
4
...
```

Here, I don't know how to tell if the `3` and the `4` is a header or belongs to the current line of `Thomas`.

Sure I can first read line by line, put them into another `Scanner`, and then read them again, but this effectively parses the whole data twice, which looks ugly to me. Is there a better way?

I would need something like a flag which tells me if a line break was encountered during the last delimiter skipping operation.

Comment: How about reading all in a big string using `stringbuffer` and then splitting it by " " (whitespace)? Then you can take the even and odd elements of the array and find out line numbers and names? or the other way round even?

Comment: Why not use `Scanner#readNextLine` and check if that `String` is numeric? If it is, then you know how many lines you need to get. if it is a String, then you know it is a record

Comment: @Ascalonian      where did you get readNextLine()?

Comment: @ha9u63ar -  Oops, i combined two things haha. Good catch! I meant `Scanner#nextLine` inside the `while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {` while-loop

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading into a separate scanner, you can read to end of line, and use `String.split`, like this:

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int count = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
        if (!scanner.hasNext()) throw new IllegalStateException("expected a name");
        String name = scanner.next();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String numStr : scanner.readLine().split(" ")) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(numStr));
        }
        ... // Do something with name and numbers
    }
}
```

This approach avoids the need to detect the difference between the last `int` on a line vs. the first integer on next line by calling `readLine()` after reading a name, i.e. in the middle of reading a line.

Comment: This is about what I suggested. But is there a more elegant way which doesn't involve parsing on two levels of abstraction (record level and single line level)?

Comment: @DanielS.: Any elegant way *will* involve parsing on two levels, since you have two different levels of structure in the file.  Anything that attempts to conflate the two, even if it works, would be pretty freaking ugly IMO.

Comment: Ok, evaluating every character once and not twice is a better way to describe elegant.

Comment: @DanielS. Using the `hasNextXYZ`+`nextXYZ` on a scanner evaluates every character twice - once to figure out what it represents, and once to construct its proper representation.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file using `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` and then start checking :

```
outer loop -->while readLine is not null 
if line matches //d+ --> read value of number and put it into count
from 0 to count do what you want to do  // inner loop
```

Comment: Just so it's said, if the line *doesn't* match `^\d+`, then the file is invalid, and you might want to consider throwing an exception.

Comment: @cHao - Right.. Then his structure is not correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("records.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = null;
   /* Read file one line at a time */
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
       int noOfRecords = Integer.parseInt(line);
       /* read the next n lines in a loop */
       while(noOfRecords != 0){
           line = reader.readLine();
           String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
           noOfRecords--;
           // do what you need to do with names and numbers
       }
   }
```

Here we're reading one line at a time, so the first time we read a line it will be an int (call it as n), from there read the next `n` lines in some inner loop. Once it's done with this inner loop it will come outside and the next time you read a line it's definitely another int or EOF. That way you don't have to deal with integer parsing exceptions and we'll read all the lines only once :)